# Google charts, pushing data to column chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, django, charts

[That is how chart looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHdxY.png)

The question is to how add data to that chart dynamically, cause currently, it is static?

Here is code of charts.js:

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart(secondChartData) {
var chartData = [["Timeout duration", "Timeout score", "Debrief duration", "Debrief score"]];
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Text", "Value", { role: "style" }, { role: "interval" }, { role: "interval" } ],
    ["Timeout duration", 28.50, "#50c4ec", 22, 35],
    ["Timeout score", 10, "#016380", 6, 17],
    ["Debrief duration", 50, "#50c4ec", 42, 58],
    ["Debrief score", 30, "#016380", 22, 38]
]);


var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1,
                      { calc: "stringify",
                        sourceColumn: 1,
                        type: "string",
                        role: "annotation" },
                      2, 3, 4]);

var options = {
    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
    colors: ['#50c4ec', '#016380', '#5fcec7', '#016380'],
    title: 'Data',
    titleTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        bold: true,
    },
    bar: {
        groupWidth: "90%"
    },
    interval: { 'style':'boxes', 'color': '#000000' },
    legend: {
        position: "none"
    },
    vAxis: {
        gridlines: {
            count: 0
        }
    }
};
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
chart.draw(view, options);
```

}

By the way, project is in Django framework.

I trying something like this, but still not working:

```
function drawChart(secondChartData) {
    var Header = ["Text", "Value", { role: "style" }, { role: "interval" }, { role: "interval" } ];
    var data = [];
    data.push(Header);


 for (var i = 0; i < secondChartData.length; i++) {
      var temp=[];
      temp.push(secondChartData[i].timeout_duration);
      temp.push(secondChartData[i].timeout_score);
      temp.push(secondChartData[i].debrief_duration);
      temp.push(secondChartData[i].debrief_score);

      data.push(temp);
}

// for (var i = 0; i < firstChartData.length; i++) {
//  data.push([secondChartData[i].timeout_duration, secondChartData[i].timeout_score, secondChartData[i].debrief_duration, secondChartData[i].debrief_score]);
// }


var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1,
                      { calc: "stringify",
                        sourceColumn: 1,
                        type: "string",
                        role: "annotation" },
                      2, 3, 4]);

var options = {
    backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
    colors: ['#50c4ec', '#016380', '#5fcec7', '#016380'],
    title: 'Data',
    titleTextStyle: {
        fontSize: 15,
        bold: true,
    },
    bar: {
        groupWidth: "90%"
    },
    intervals: { 'style':'box', 'color': '#000000' },
    interval: { 'style':'box', 'color': 'rgb(0,0,0)' },
    legend: {
        position: "none"
    },
    vAxis: {
        gridlines: {
            count: 0
        }
    }
};
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
chart.draw(view, options);
```

}

Don't know how to grab the data from Django and display it in the chart.

Here is how I connected the JS to the template:

```
{% block extra_js %}
<script src="{% static 'js/charts.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock extra_js %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, you can either render the dynamic data in a `<script>` tag in the HTML file that includes this JavaScript or you can render the `charts.js` file itself dynamically as a URL served by Django. In the latter case you will want to make sure to specify the `content_type` in the render. In either case you will probably want to make use of the [`{% escapejs %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#escapejs) filter.

EDIT based on your update:

In that case, the easiest thing would be to do something like

```
{% block extra_js %}
<script>
let data = []
{% for d in data_from_django %}
    data.push("{{ d }}");
</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/charts.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock extra_js %}
```

Comment: Honestly didn't get fully your explanation( As I understood I need a  for loop to fulfill the data array. And I do not know how to grab data from the Django to display it in chart

Comment: Can you add some detail about where and how you're rendering the file that includes this JavaScript?

Comment: Added the code how I connected js to the template. If you meant this